# downlaod adobe connect recorded with youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl

I'm trying to download this adobe connect recorded class wtih youtube-dl but it shows me error. can help me?

```
http://webinar2.um.ac.ir/p235bgxwomm/?OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=02580f34ad3e972c95f8a52eee4700b15783db104789f9c87909d1dedcb8f6bf
```

error:

```
youtube-dl.exe http://webinar2.um.ac.ir/p235bgxwomm/?OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=02580f34ad3e972c95f8a52eee4700b15783db104789f9c87909d1dedcb8f6bf
[generic] ?OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=02580f34ad3e972c95f8a52eee4700b15783db104789f9c87909d1dedcb8f6bf: Requesting header
WARNING: Falling back on generic information extractor.
[generic] ?OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=02580f34ad3e972c95f8a52eee4700b15783db104789f9c87909d1dedcb8f6bf: Downloading webpage
[generic] ?OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=02580f34ad3e972c95f8a52eee4700b15783db104789f9c87909d1dedcb8f6bf: Extracting information
ERROR: Unsupported URL: http://webinar2.um.ac.ir/p235bgxwomm/?OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=02580f34ad3e972c95f8a52eee4700b15783db104789f9c87909d1dedcb8f6bf
```

I'm sure that it is a adobe connect record!

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to use youtube-dl for adobe connect recorded class too, but I was unsuccessful. There is a simple solution for downloading your recorded class; your adobe connect URL should look like this:

```
http://webinar2.um.ac.ir/abcdefghijk/
```

Add this to the end:

```
output/filename.zip?download=zip
```

So your URL should look like this:

```
http://webinar2.um.ac.ir/abcdefghijk/output/filename.zip?download=zip
```

Then, it will give you a zip file containing the resources of the recorded class. One of the disadvantages of this method is that you may need to add the audio to the video yourself. Sometimes there is more than one file for a whole class; for example, in my case, there was 3 file each containing about 20 minutes of a 60 minutes class.